# Pushing my PS1 prompt over ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, prompt

I use a specific "PS1" prompt that I like. I share a few logins with other other people on a few different servers. I was wondering if there was a way to specify in my local bash profile a remote prompt, or any other way other then copy and pasting each time I remote in.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Upload a file on each remote machine, say `~/.my_custom_bashrc`, with your custom `bash` configuration, (in this case `PS1=...`) then launch `ssh` with:

```
ssh user@host -t "bash --rcfile ~/.my_custom_bashrc -i"
```

You can easily use a `bash` function as wrapper for readability.

Comment: There's an answer, currently way at the bottom, that has an elegant, no-file-upload way to just cat together system bashrc and current-shell-variables... no file uploads, no altering system files. Very clean.  https://superuser.com/a/1542498/539101

Answer (score 12):

If you just want to send the `PS1` variable, and it doesn't contain a `'` (single quote), try:

```
ssh targethost -t "PS1='$PS1'; exec bash"
```

The local `.bashrc` may well overwrite `PS1` though (thanks to [Dennis Williamson](https://superuser.com/questions/221001/pushing-my-ps1-prompt-over-ssh/221017#221017) for pointing this out).

There are [ways to transmit environment variables over ssh](https://superuser.com/questions/207200/how-can-i-set-environment-variables-for-a-remote-rsync-process/207262#207262), but they're typically disabled in the server configuration. If the `PermitUserEnvironment` directive is enabled in the [server configuration](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=sshd_config&sektion=5) and each user has their own key pair (yeah, you might not be so lucky), you can add `environment="PS1=…"` to the line in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` corresponding to your key.

If you'd like to keep your own configuration on a shared user account, you can create your own configuration file directory and set the `HOME` environment variable to point to that directory.

```
ssh targethost mkdir mrstatic.home
scp .bashrc targethost:mrstatic.home/
```

Create symbolic links in the `mrstatic.home` directory pointing back to the corresponding entry in the parent directory when you want to share a file with the other users.

Then, log in with

```
ssh targethost -t 'HOME=~/mrstatic.home; exec bash'`
```

If you're willing to modify the remote `.profile` (or other initialisation file), you can probably automate your settings. Many sites allow `LC_*` environment variables through (normally they are used for locale settings). If both these conditions are met, you can set a variable that isn't actually used for locales, say `LC_USER`, on the client side, and test it in the server `.profile`.

(Of course shared accounts are a bad idea, but I realize you may not be in a position to change that situation.)

Answer (score 3):

```
ssh -t user@host "remote='$PS1' bash -i"
```

Then, at the prompt:

```
PS1=$remote
```

Comment: A sophisticated bash prompt is likely to break if it's not quoted (coming from you, I'm surprised). And why the extra command, and not just `"PS1='$PS1' bash -i"` (and why not `exec`, too)?

Comment: @Gilles: Missing quoting: sloppiness. Extra command: it wouldn't be unusual for `PS1` to be overwritten during shell startup. No exec: during testing on my system it didn't seem to make any difference - no extra process.

Comment: Oh, yes, that's a good point, the local `.bashrc` is likely to overwrite `PS1`.

Answer (score 3):

Put your PS1 prompt in ~/.ssh/environment and ssh session will carry it to every host you login. It works for me with openssh 4.3p2 .

Comment: This only works if the server's configuration has enabled `PermitUserEnvironment`, which is off by default.

Answer (score 3):

To restore arbitrary environment variables from your client on the server use the following bash command to connect to your ssh-server. In The following example we restore `PS1` and `PS2`.
If you want to send more variables to the server simply add their names *without* a `$` after `PS2`.

```
ssh -t user@server "exec bash --rcfile <(cat /etc/bash.bashrc ~/.bashrc 2> /dev/null; printf '%s\n' $(printf %q "$(declare -p PS1 PS2)"))"
```

This command sets the given variables (here `PS1` and `PS2`) *after* the original rc-files from the server were sourced (you may have to adapt this list, for instance by adding `~/.profile`). Therefore you end up with your usual environment from the server (if the default shell on the server is bash) *and* the given variables from the client (these may overwrite variables set by `server`'s rc-files).

- No `scp` or temporary files needed.
- No restrictions on the content of the variables to be pushed.
- No special requirements on the ssh server settings.

Comment: This is a really, really good way to solve this problem...  cat the existing files together,  then use printf to print current shell variables into assignment statements.  Clever!

Answer (score 1):

you can specify environment variables on the client side and if the ssh-server allows it (check man sshd-config), these variables are copied to the session when you log into the machine.

so, you would have to configure the .bashrc on the server to check an existing PS1 (or whatever variable) and only set PS1 if it is not set already.

or, which make things simpler, you bundle your settings into a function .. and deploy that function either as a special file your source on demand (`source joes_bashrc`) or directly to the .bashrc. having your own file seems a bit more robust. the other folks might use your settings but are not forced to do so.

Comment: `export PS1="${PS1:-$my_default_PS1}"` - only set if PS1 is empty

Comment: `export PS1="${PS1:+$new_prefix $PS1 $new_suffix}"` - only build new string if PS1 is already set, and use current PS1 value in new result.

Comment: If you're running over ssh, will want to escape the `\$PS1` to read the value on the server.  You could get dirty w/ sed or whatever else you want inside the string. 
`export PS1=\${PS1:+ \$(alter_server_ps1 "\$PS1") }`

Answer (score 1):

**Do not share logins.** SSH as yourself, then do `sudo -su shareduser` (`-s` means "shell").

Make `sudo` keep your home directory:

```
Defaults env_keep += "HOME"
```

Comment: When I get promoted I will try and enact that policy but for now I am stuck with this.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna do it without needing an extra scp you can do something like this:

`ssh -t srvname ' cp ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc.n &>/dev/null ; echo "LS_COLORS=\"no=00:fi=00:ETC:ETC:ETC\";" >> ~/.bashrc.n ; echo "export LS_COLORS" >> ~/.bashrc.n ; echo "alias ls=\"ls --color=auto\";" >> ~/.bashrc.n ; exec bash --rcfile ~/.bashrc.n'`

That'll generate a .bashrc.n that's based on the servers bashrc but with your overrides.

Comment: This is why some people are afraid of terminals.

Comment: just fyi...  echo is perfectly happy w/ multiline strings.  Stackoverflow comments, however, don't support them but you can do: `echo "$(< ~/.bashrc) <newline>THING='blah'<newline>" > ~/.bashrc.n`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is IMHO :

```
ssh user@server 'PROMPT_COMMAND=export PS1="changeme $" bash -li;'
```

Comment: I’m not sure that works; it seems to be missing a layer of quotes.  Even if it did, setting `PROMPT_COMMAND` (which executes every time the shell issues a prompt) seems to be a very heavy-handed way of solving this problem.  And, since it’s somewhat arcane, any answer that suggests it really should have an explanation of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re willing to intrude imperceptibly on your colleagues,
and you can trust them not to interfere with your preference,
then I suggest a combination of [cYrus’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/221001/150988#221025),
[akira’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/221001/150988#221014) and [Dennis Williamson’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/221001/150988#221017).

1. On each server, edit `~/.bashrc` and add

   ```
   if [ "$Unf" = 1 ]                       # Special code for Unfundednut
   then
       PS1="(your desired prompt)"
       (any other customizations you want)
   fi
   ```

   at the end. 
   While your colleagues “would not appreciate [you]
   writing over the base profile”,
   they won’t be aware of this unless they go looking for it.
2. When you login to a remote server,
   do

   ```
   ssh -t user@host "Unf=1 bash -i"
   ```

   While you will probably want to put that
   into an alias or shell function in your local account,
   it is short enough — shorter than any of the other answers —
   that you could easily just type it manually.

I believe that this is fairly clear, but: 
the `ssh` command causes the `Unf` variable
to be set on the remote server when you log into it. 
That will invoke your code in the remote `.bashrc`,
which will put your customization(s) into effect. 
Since you put your code at the end of `.bashrc`,
it will override the general settings earlier in the file.

Disclosure: I have not tested this.

Answer (score -2):

You could do stuff like mounting your home over sshfs/nfs, but the easiest solution is to scp your bashrc across to the new machine. This also brings aliases and stuff.

Comment: As I stated in my question I share these logins with other people. I am quite sure they would not appreciate me writing over the base profile.

Comment: Mounting $HOME over NFS is insane. Just sayin'.

Comment: lol, mounting user HOME over NFS or other shared drive technology is very common if you want to have a home directory that comes with you to all machines...