# How do I get ssh to read the destination's `.bashrc`?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, arch-linux

I have two Linux computers at work, a desktop and a laptop, running Openssh under Arch Linux. Under my standard logins, I have a customized `.bashrc` file inside my home folder on both computers.

**Here's the question:** When I `ssh` to the desktop, I'm presented with a pretty customized bash (meaning the `.bashrc` file has been read). When I `ssh` to the laptop, I'm presented with a plain and gray bash, and I have to manually run `exec bash` (so it will read my custom `.bashrc`). **Why?**

I must have configured something different on one of these computers that's causing the difference, but I can't figure out what. The ssh command I'm running is a simple `ssh username@host` (with a clean `.ssh/config` file) in both cases.

Note: There is already a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/221001/pushing-my-ps1-prompt-over-ssh) asking how to use your `.bashrc` over ssh, I'm not asking that. I just want to know **why** one of the hosts is using it, but the other isn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does the `.bash_profile` (or `.profile` if `.bash_profile` does not exist) run `. .bashrc` or `source .bashrc` at some point? If not, then your `.bashrc` will not be used when logging in via `ssh`, as `ssh` always starts bash as a "login" shell, which never reads `.bashrc` by default.

Comment: Yep that was it. I have no idea why the two machines had different `.bash_profile`s, but that's what was causing it.