# Keep your terminal's PS1 over SSH

Tags: terminal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pushing my PS1 prompt over ssh](https://superuser.com/questions/221001/pushing-my-ps1-prompt-over-ssh)

I like to have the username cyan and the host red in my laptop and server machine's PS1 like so:

[image: PS1 example]

The problem is, when I install a new server and SSH onto it, I have to set the PS1 every time.

Is there a way to use my personal PS1 when I SSH onto a new box?
I'm using OS X Lion with the Apple Terminal application.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep your dotfiles in a git repo and clone that out to any new system you need to use. Either that, or (if these servers are all on the same LAN) set up shared home directories via NFS.

Comment: That's basically what I do, only with rsync.